# Unused local variable compiler error when it is used

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, unused-variables

I've got a weird one here. I'm getting the compiler error "Unused local variable" for a variable that is used!

```
If bUpdate Then
   Dim fclm As New frmNewClaim : GetOpenForm(fclm)
   With fclm ' <-------------------
       .something = x
   End With
 End If
```

The sub GetOpenForm just attaches to a form if it is already open

I have the exact same code (the Dim/With) in other parts of the application that are not being complained about. I've tried recompiling, but the error remains.

What is going on here?

Comment: Then delete your question instead of leaving the clutter behind.

Comment: Not sure what your doing. Try this instead `Dim fclm As frmNewClaim = GetOpenForm(fclm)`

Comment: It's a subroutine.  I'd have to change over a hundred other lines that are pretty much identical, that work to "fix" this one line.